# how to get cascading entities to be disassociated or remove from the database?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, cascade

In my application I have the following model relationship.

```
public class EntityA {
    (...)
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "a")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    private List<EntityB> listOfBs;
    (...) // and getters and setters
}

public class EntityB {
    (...)
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idA")
    private EntityA a;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "b")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    private List<EntityC> listOfCs;
    (...) // and getters and setters
}

public class EntityC {
    (...)
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idB")
    private EntityB b;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "c")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    private List<EntityD> listOfDs;
    (...) // and getters and setters
}

public class EntityD {
    (...)
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idC")
    private EntityC c;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "d")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    private List<EntityE> listOfEs;
    (...) // and getters and setters
}

public class EntityE {
    (...)
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idD")
    private EntityD d;
    private Date dateA;
    private Date dateB;
    private Float float;
    private String stringX;
    (...) // and getters and setters
}
```

The idea here is:

- each `EntityA` can have one or more `EntityBs` that are associated
  from a DualListBox element;
- each `EntityB` can be assigned to only
  one `EntityA`;
- each `EntityB` can have one or more `EntityCs`. When
  the `EntityC` is created, a List<`EntityD`> is created, one `EntityD`
  is created and added to `listOfDs` and set into `EntityC`. Also, a
  List<`EntityE`> is created, one `EntityE` is created and added to
  `listOfEs` and set into `EntityD`.

I hope I managed to make myself clear on the business rules above.

The problem is the removal of an `EntityA` and its cascading effect.

On my `EntityAService`The code I'm trying is:

```
public removeA(String idA) {
    A a = service.findAById(idA);

    for (EntityB b : a.getListOfBs()) {
        for (EntityC c : b.getListOfDs()) {
            for (EntityD d : c.getListOfDs()) {
                for (EntityE e : d.getListOfEs()) {
                    service.removeE(e);
                }
                service.removeD(d);
            }
        service.removeC(c);
        }
    b.setA(null);
    }
    a.setListOfBs(null);
    update(a);
    remove(a);
}
```

When I try to remove an `entityA`, I the `entityBs` are disassociated from  `entityA`, but all `entityC`s associated to a `EntityB` are kept. Same goes, respectively, to `entityD`s and `entityE`s.

I have been at this for a while now but still can't see the problem. What's going on and how to fix?

Comment: Can't you just add cascading rules to your mappings and have the framework handle this? https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Cascading

Comment: Can you post what service.removeX does? Do you the delete queries of hibernate on the log?